# What is the quickest way to determine what code will be affected by a refactoring?

Tags: refactoring, methodology, procedure

I'm using Eclipse and Java, but the answer doesn't need to be specific to those.  I'm sure platform specific answers will get plenty of upvotes if they're far quicker than non-platform specific ones.

Right now I'm using

`grep "classname" find . -regex .*\.java > uses_classname.txt`

to find code that might be affected by a change to the class.  If there are only a few lines returned by this, I can look at it manually as it is.  Otherwise, I can grep again to find the specific methods I'm modifying.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Assuming that by 'refactoring` you mean 'renaming': In Eclipse, Right-click the method name, References -> Workspace?

Comment: What about... performing the refactoring? If you are using version control and you don't have any uncommitted changes, all modified files are the ones touched by refactoring.

Comment: Tomasz, that assumes you've checked out the whole code base into your workspace, rather than a portion of the code base that compiles independently.  (Which may itself not be the best practice.)

Comment: @TheNail, I don't mean renaming, I mean possibly eliminating a method or changing parameters or something along those lines.  Obviously another possible refactoring would be to leave it as is, and add new methods so the old one can gradually be used in less code.

Comment: Ok, then this Eclipse feature should also be useful. It simply shows you where the method is currently being used. BTW, the `grep`-method suffers from the same limitation as a refactoring in Eclipse if you haven't checked out a portion of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Just being a bit of a librarian here:]*

Finding references to a **Java** method/class:

> [How can I find all the methods that call a given method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java)
>
> [How can I find references of a class in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839156/how-can-i-find-references-of-a-class-in-eclipse)

References to Java annotations:

> [How to Check References of Annotated Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681266/how-to-check-references-of-annotated-methods)

Finding references to 'derived' methods in Eclipse:

> [Eclipse Specific: Is it possible to find references of use of derived methods in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856517/eclipse-specific-is-it-possible-to-find-references-of-use-of-derived-methods-in)

How to do it with **VIM**:

> [Is it possible to find usage of java classes or methods in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459669/is-it-possible-to-find-usage-of-java-classes-or-methods-in-vim)

And with **Emacs**:

> [How can I find the references of a class, method, variable in Emacs with Etags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592099/how-can-i-find-the-references-of-a-class-method-variable-in-emacs-with-etags)

Finding (the number of) references to a method in **C#**:

> [How do you programmatically identify the number of references to a method with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106329/how-do-you-programmatically-identify-the-number-of-references-to-a-method-with-c)

Nice to read: how to find methods that are ***not* used in C#/.NET**:

> [Find unused code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code)
>
> [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c)

On refactoring of **PHP** code:

> [Tools for PHP code refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758/tools-for-php-code-refactoring)

Finding references in **Smalltalk**:

> [Find references to string/symbol/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885196/find-references-to-string-symbol-method)

Finding references in (Apple) **Xcode** seems to be a popular question:

> [Find method references in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145045/how-to-find-method-references-in-xcode)
>
> [Xcode: view references for a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831845/xcode-view-references-for-a-variable)
>
> [Finding all references of a variable or a method in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457190/finding-all-references-of-a-variable-or-a-method-in-xcode4)

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to use [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and practice [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Test-driven_development_cycle). After refactoring, re-running your test cases will tell you whether any existing functionality has been damaged. Moreover, since you are actually testing the code rather than grep'ing over method names, you can get full backtrace, making debugging much easier. A good introduction to JUnit can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/ant/ant_chap04.pdf).

Comment: I like the idea of using unit tests to verify that things are still working after the refactor, but that does not answer the question: How long is it going to take? which generally is answered by knowing which classes are going to be refactored and how many times they are being used in your software.